# passing data from mysql data from a certain page to another

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have this program that i want to transfer from another page but i couldn't. i'm using POST method. my plan is to edit the certain data to another page. so i can design it neatly. **(this is an old code ) its a working code. back then i used to edit the data within the page with no problem.

```
$sql_statement  = "SELECT ssn, lastname, firstname ";
$sql_statement .= "FROM author ";
$sql_statement .= "ORDER BY lastname, firstname ";

$result = mysql_query($sql_statement);

$outputDisplay = "";
$myrowcount = 0;

if (!$result) {
    $outputDisplay .= "<br /><font color=red>MySQL No: ".mysql_errno();
    $outputDisplay .= "<br />MySQL Error: ".mysql_error();
    $outputDisplay .= "<br />SQL Statement: ".$sql_statement;
    $outputDisplay .= "<br />MySQL Affected Rows: ".mysql_affected_rows()."</font><br />";
} else {

    $outputDisplay  = "<h3>Author Table Data</h3>";

    $outputDisplay .= '<table border=1 style="color: black;">';
    $outputDisplay .= '<tr><th>SSN</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th></tr>';

    $numresults = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++)
    {
        if (!($i % 2) == 0)
        {
             $outputDisplay .= "<tr style=\"background-color: #F5DEB3;\">";
        } else {
             $outputDisplay .= "<tr style=\"background-color: white;\">";
        }

        $myrowcount++;

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $ssn       = $row['ssn'];
        $lastname  = $row['lastname'];
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];



        $outputDisplay .= "<td><input type='submit' name='updateauthor' value='".$ssn."' /></td>";
        $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$lastname."</td>";
        $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$firstname."</td>";

        $outputDisplay .= "</tr>";
    }

    $outputDisplay .= "</table>";

}
```

if you're wondering on how did i got this code. i can post my previous code.

Comment: are you looking for an edit button option, am  i r8?

Comment: i do have one . you can click that ssn because its an submit type

Comment: What exactly is the problem? And where does `$updateauthor` come from? The first time we see it, you compare it to `Save Changes`

Comment: opps that wasnt suppose to be there ill edit

Comment: pass the ssn to the next page and retrieve all data from mysql with  ssn id.

Comment: yes im using the post method is that correct ? can you give me an example ?

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="updateauthor" value="<?php echo $ssn;?>" />`

Comment: then access the variable passed page - `$_GET['updateauthor']` or `$_POST['updateauthor']`

Comment: thanks , but still not work

Comment: side note: please do not use deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Comment: You can use $_GET[] to carry single data from current page to another page.. or data is multiple then store it in a session.

Comment: yes @PHPGeek thats exactly what i want to pass multiple data. but how do i exactly do that.

Comment: Just store the data into a variable and redirect to another page with querystring or store data in an array and add the array to session variable as we creates a session.